# The Deletion function in the JavaScript file deletes two Bookmarks at once/same-time

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, youtube, bookmarks, chrome-extension-manifest-v3

The details of the issue has been addressed into the Github Issues Section. I will be providing the link of the same in which detailed explanation has been provided for the same...
It would be very kind if the pull-request is been created for the same.

Link to the issue/repository:
https://github.com/utkarshtambe10/videomark-chromeExtension/issues/3

I tried a-lot for resolving the issue by using `event.stopImmediatePropagation()` function of JavaScript but using that in-turn solves issue halfway as after reloading the same webpage, the deleted bookmarks also appear again which makes the chrome-extension of no-use....

Thanking in advance if help is provided....

Reference code attached below:

```
const onDelete = async e => {
    const activeTab = await getActiveTabURL();
    const bookmarkTime = e.target.parentNode.parentNode.getAttribute("timestamp");
    const bookmarkElementToDelete = document.getElementById("bookmark-" + bookmarkTime);

    bookmarkElementToDelete.parentNode.removeChild(bookmarkElementToDelete);

    chrome.tabs.sendMessage(activeTab.id, {
        type: "DELETE",
        value: bookmarkTime
    }, viewBookmarks);
};
```

Answer (score 0):

The bug is in addNewBookmarkEventHandler()

You write the new bookmark to Storage, but you're don't update currentVideoBookmarks.
That means currentVideoBookmarks always lags one bookmark behind Storage.

The chrome.runtime.onMessage handler (type === "DELETE") gets the bookmarks from currentVideoBookmarks, not from Storage.

```
currentVideoBookmarks = currentVideoBookmarks.filter((b) => b.time != value);
chrome.storage.sync.set({[currentVideo]: JSON.stringify(currentVideoBookmarks)});
```

Please read the tutorial about [Debugging extensions](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/mv3/tut_debugging/).

contentScript.js

```
let currentVideoBookmarks = [];

const addNewBookmarkEventHandler = async () => {
    const currentTime = youtubePlayer.currentTime;
    const newBookmark = {
        time: currentTime,
        desc: "Bookmark at " + getTime(currentTime)
    };
    currentVideoBookmarks = await fetchBookmarks();
    
    chrome.storage.sync.set({
        [currentVideo]: JSON.stringify([...currentVideoBookmarks, newBookmark].sort((a, b) => a.time - b.time))
    });
};

chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener((obj, sender, response) => {
    const { type, value, videoId } = obj;
    
    if (type === "NEW") {
        currentVideo = videoId;
        newVideoLoaded();
    } else if(type === "PLAY") {
        youtubePlayer.currentTime = value;
    } else if(type === "DELETE") {
        currentVideoBookmarks = currentVideoBookmarks.filter((b) => b.time != value);
        chrome.storage.sync.set({[currentVideo]: JSON.stringify(currentVideoBookmarks)});
        
        response(currentVideoBookmarks);
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. Even after reading the attached documentation, I am not able to figure-out what should be added to the code but got your point about what is giving me the error. Would you please edit that line of code? And attach it for the same?